# Are there any other shows that actively show humans dating animals?

Tags: alvin-and-the-chipmunks

So my kids watch Alvin and the Chipmunks on Nick - the new one.  I know it is innocent but I find it very bizarre that human girls are trying to date Alvin every other episode.  I don't think I can recall any other shows that have a straight up animal dating a human.

To be clear, not talking about sci-fi creatures, aliens, or anything in between.  I am talking about a character that is a straight up animal that a human is seeking to date or in love with.  Any other examples?

Comment: Happens many, many times with Brian in *Family Guy*.

Comment: @Walt - I don't watch Family Guy.  Are they doing it in a serious way or is it sarcastic/funny?

Comment: Well, it's a comedy. But he's the family dog and dates humans. And no one makes a fuss about it.

Comment: @blankip yeah, that's what your parents are paying for your college, so you can f**k a dog. But they have done it seriously and as a throw away joke. Brian has had full relationships with human women.

Comment: American guy, Haley dates a koala. Bee movie, she dumps a guy to date a bee. A bee that sounds like Jerry Seinfeld... Multiple women have married Donald Trump.

Comment: Family Guy, American Dad, [Ted](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637725/)... What the hell, Seth MacFarlane?

Comment: @BilltheLizard - A talking stuffed animal is not an animal, however maybe it is more disturbing.

Comment: This seems incredibly broad. I've no idea what a good answer would look like